# Equivalence of categories implying, under some special hypothesis, isomorphism of categories

Tags: category-theory

If two categories $C$ and $D$ are equivalent, this implies that there's a bijection between the isomorphism classes of objects of $C$ and the isomorphism classes of objects of $D$. If we furthermore assume that for each isomorphism class of objects of $C$, the corresponding isomorphism class of objects of $D$ has the same cardinality, does it follow that $C$ is isomorphic to $D$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Let $[X]$ denote the isomorphism class of $X$, and let $F : C \to D$ be a functor giving rise to an equivalence of categories (that is, fully faithful and essentially surjective). Suppose that $\forall X \in C |[X]| = |[F(X)]|$.

Note that if $[X] = [Y]$ then $[F(X)] = [F(Y)]$.

Choose, for each isomorphism class $[X]$, a bijection $b_{[X]} : [X] \to [F(X)]$.

Choose, for each $X$, an isomorphism $i_X : F(X) \to b_{[X]}(X)$.

Define a new functor $G : C \to D$ which acts on objects by $G(X) = b_{[X]}(X)$ and which acts on arrows $f : A \to B$ by $G(f) = i_B \circ F(f) \circ i_A^{-1}$.

Then $G$ is an isomorphism of categories since it is a bijection on objects and is fully faithful.

Comment: Thanks! Then $G$ is fully faithful and bijective on objects up to equality. Does this imply that $G$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @user974038 Yes, just invert the map on objects and on each hom set. The inverse is a functor since the original map is.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!